# How to update from Odin to Jolnir

Tags: updates

I only just started being comfortable with my EOS 6 Odin... and I see that 6.1 Jolnir is available.

What is not clear to me: how do I update existing Odin installation to Jolnir?
or do I need to "update" my Odin at all?

Most (all) instructions on the web seem to concentrate on new downloaders, I couldn't find anything about upgrading from 6 to 6.1 ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/elementary/os/wiki/elementary-OS-6.1-J%C3%B3lnir-FAQ), the only thing you need to do is update from AppCenter.

Comment: Thank you, that answers the question (I like BTW when the say"it is straightforward to manually install the latest version while retaining your personal data" - updating from 5 to 6 was painful... and not straightforward at all, but I guess that's another story)